# CSS Drop-down menu alignment problems

Tags: html, css, menu

I am having some issues wrapping my head around this problem. Basically I have created a drop down menu and I can't get it to position correctly. I have the background in blue and the menu background in black so you can see how it comes over the bottom of my blue background. I want the black to be centered in the blue as well it would be nice if I could get some help centering the text in the middle of the menu without having to resort to line-height.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mzz2u/

HTML

```
<div id="nav">


<ul id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Punching Bags</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Protection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wholesales</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Equipment Catalogue</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wholesale Inqueries</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Direct Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">YouTube Channel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LinkedIn Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook Page</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
background-color: #004f99;
height: 40px;
vertical-align: text-middle;
}
#main-nav,
#main-nav ul {
list-style: none;
}
#main-nav {
float: left;
background-color: #000000;
}
#main-nav > li {
float: left;
height: 40px;
}
#main-nav li a {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 2.0em;
text-decoration: none;
}
#main-nav ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
width: 150px;
}
#main-nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#main-nav {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
background-image: url('../images/menubg.jpg');
}
#main-nav > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
}
#main-nav > li:hover > a {
color: #888888;
background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#main-nav ul {
background-color: #111111;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
}
#main-nav ul li:hover a {
background: #888888;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look of what I did in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mzz2u/1/

Basically I've removed `vertical-align: text-middle;` from #nav and stablished `display: block; text-align: center;` to keep it full width and align to center the wrapped nav, then in the ul nav I've put `display: inline-block;` to assign only neccesary auto-width and `float: none; margin: 0 auto;` to center into the parent.

I hope this helps you, be careful when using display properties, most time for common elements and works you should use `block, inline-block, none` but for some tricks around the web you may be use the other possibilities.

---

Edit: If you want to center the content of the link without having to set `line-height: 40px` lets add `vertical-align:middle;  display: table-cell;` to "a" element inside "li"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tVAGw/

Real easy to center the text if you're not stuck on it being 40px. 
The problem with alignment was the default padding on `#main-nav ul`

Answer (score 0):

Basically: http://jsfiddle.net/p7q87/

What I did:

```
++ #main-nav {margin: 0;}
++ #main-nav li a { position: relative; top: 50%; margin-top: -12px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well:

```
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu{right:0;left:0}
```

at:

```
http://www.dinewine.com/startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6/index.html
```